# ROS and Raspberry Pi 3 Slam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am making robot with raspberyy pi 3 that create map ı mean slam project. I install ros kinetic on raspberry pi 3 but ı dont know what is the next. I saw how to create simulation part and ı make it but ı dont know where  ı start now

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257088/ros-and-raspberry-pi-3-slam/) by [yunusemretusun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29560/yunusemretusun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, what exactly are you building? Which sensors do you have?

Generally speaking, your robot will need to publish the tf transformations of the base and odometry. Also, the transformation between the base and the image sensor you have (it can be a laser rangefinder, Kinect, or others). If you have a Kinect, you will need to transform the pointcloud in a laserscan (please refer to this package http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan)

Then, try some SLAM algorithms. I suggest GMapping to get started since it's well maintained and cover most of the situations http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yunusemretusun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29560/yunusemretusun/) on 2017-03-17**:
I am building two wheel robot and ı will buy a rp lidar sensor and yes motor with encoder.First I thought do motor control and read encoder variable on ros and then the other step.And I think ı use raspberry pi 3 and arduino.Arduino make the motor control What is your opinon?Any advice will be great

**Comment by [rhoude57](https://answers.ros.org/users/31435/rhoude57/) on 2017-08-03**:
Hi,
I intend to do something similar. My main SLAM sensor will be a Scanse Sweep Lidar. The Raspberry Pi 3 and Sweep sensor will ride on a tracked DAGU Rover 5 chassis controlled by a Beagleboard Blue board running the ArduRover autopilot. The rover will have a GPS and compass for outdoor missions.